# Pages are rendering in IE-version7 not in edge mode until developer tool is opened

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

My website is working properly in chrome and Firefox, but not in IE, by default its opening in version-7 mode not in edge mode. But if i open the developer tool then page is again rendering and changed into version edge(latest version). please help me out.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Reference link:
http://www.resmed.com/in/en/index.html

Regards,
Prabhu Shanmugam

Comment: This is literally the kind of thing that you hire a developer for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to force edge mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Zuluk, already i have tried, but still it is not working in specific network(resmed network), but in another network it works properly.